# How to save a value of a private field (that was gotten in a method) in an object?

Tags: java

I can't figure out the way to save the supplierName value in a class object. I'm trying to change it in an addItem method using user input, and store it in a class object. It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to change my constructor? Or use a getter method?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PurchasedItem extends Item {

    private String suppplierName;

    public PurchasedItem() {}

    @Override
    public boolean addItem(Scanner input) {
        super.addItem(input);   

        System.out.print("Enter the name of the supplier: ");
        suppplierName = input.next();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        String str = super.toString();
        return str + " Supplier: " + suppplierName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm...what is your question? It makes no sense the way it's currently stated

Comment: It's not the best idea to request this kind of information from within the `PurchasedItem`, it's really not it's responsibility to perform this operation.  That information should be gathered before hand and then applied to the object either via the constructor or possibly a setter, depending on you design needs

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to allow the constructor to take an argument such as:

```
public PurchasedItem(String constructorArgument){
    supplierName = constructorArgument;
}
```

Then, you can do something like: `PurchasedItem item = new PurchasedItem("some supplier");`.

Since the class variable is private, you will also need getters/setters.

For instance:

**Setter:**

```
public void setSupplierName(String s){
    this.supplierName = s;
}
```

**Getter:**

```
public String getSupplierName(){
    return this.supplierName
}
```

Then to manipulate, you'd do something like:

```
item.setSupplierName("some company");
item.getsupplierName();
```

Though, you should be conscious of thread safety in regards to utilising setters.

Comment: Looking at the code example that the OP sent I don't think that this answer is correct. There is no **need** to allow the constructor to take an argument. There is also no **need** for *getter* and *setter* methods since, in the example, the variable only is used within the class scope. The way the OP is setting `supplierName` is correct.

Comment: @RaulSauco I'd say that the way the OP is setting the supplier name is a poor approach, as the object itself shouldn't be asking the user for details. Instead, that value should obtained else where and the object created with the value or it passed via a setter as demonstrated.  It would provide the functionality the OP is seeking

Comment: @Aremis I like the answer generally, but I might suggest that the setter would make the object mutable, which "may" not be part of the intended design - it's a nit-pick on my part but might be worth noting the side effect to the OP

Comment: @MadProgrammer I agree with that, I posted the comment because the answer uses the word **need**: *You will need to allow the constructor...*, *...you will also need getters/setters...*. I also think that the OP's approach is not good but I don't think that the answer is correct as it is written right now. I don't really understand what the question is though.

Comment: @RaulSauco Based on my "loose" understanding of the question, you're heading the OP in the right question

Comment: I would say that the main problem is to have an `addItem` method inside the `PurchasedItem` class, it seems like the responsibility of adding an item should lay outside the `Item` class or it's descendents. For example, if we are storing the `PurchasedItem` objects in a collection, we could add them like: collection.add(newItem) where newItem would have been created with the constructor that @Artemis proposes on this answer.